# cannot mount /dev/loop1 on /cow

Tags: mount, live-usb, initramfs, usb-creator

I am trying to install ubuntu 12.10 64bit using a liveUsb and I got this message :

`cannot mount /dev/loop1 on /cow` which shows up after clicking on "try Ubuntu before installing" or install Ubuntu".

I tried using `nomodeset` option and I ended up with this error :

```
initramfs) unable to find a medium containing a live file system
```

I used Startup Disk Creator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I solved the problem.

All I had to do is to choose the "Discard changes after shutdown" option when I was using `Start up disk creator` program to create my LiveUsb.

Is this a bug ?

Answer (score 3):

Did you wait for the persistence file to be created?

If not, this is a reasonable error since the file will be corrupt. That's why it worked when you used the option "Discard changes".

Mind that for a 4Gb persistence file it takes about 10 minutes to write it in a USB 2.0.

Comment: I am not sure if I have waited or not. all I did is click erase the USB and then install. waited for everything to finish, pressed OK after it finished installing and restarted my PC.

Answer (score 0):

Run again Universal USB installer and this time make sure you check the option format drive (usb) when using universal usb installer. That's all.